# get variable value from array foreach PHP

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I'm using array foreach to get the value.

```
foreach($movie as $key=>$value) {
    if($key == 0) {
        echo $_SESSION['movie'] = $value;  //output1
    } else {
        echo $_SESSION['movie'] =  ", ".$value; 
    }   
}

echo $value; //output2
```

When it echo for output1:

> movie1,movie2,movie3

When output 2:

> movie3

I would like to use the variable $value outside of **foreach** but I can't get **output1** result, and get only **output2** result.

My desired output2:

> movie1,movie2,movie3

Comment: push the values into an array then use them outside the for loop block.

Comment: You need to append the values to your `$value` variable atm you assign it to `$_SESSION['movie']`.

Comment: `implode(',', $movie)`

Comment: thank you so much @AlexHowansky ! it works like a charm, didn't know it would be that simple. Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're iterating the `$movie` array just to print the movies as a comma separated string, you don't need to.

```
echo implode(',', $movie);
```

Comment: And here is the [documentation](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)

Answer (score 0):

> Assign your values to `array` inside foreach.

```
foreach($movie as $key=>$value){
 $moviename[]=$value;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to store the string in $_SESSION['movie']? Looks like you are confusing yourself a bit there.

```
foreach($movie as $key=>$value){
    if($key === 0){
        $_SESSION['movie'] = $value; 
    }else{
        $_SESSION['movie'] .=  ", ".$value; 
    }   
}
echo $_SESSION['movie']; //output2
```

Will result in

> Movie1,Movie2,Movie3

You could just use implode. https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php eg:

```
$movie = array(0 => 'Movie1', 1 => 'Movie2', 2 => 'Movie3');
$movie_str = implode(',', $movie);
echo movie_str;
```

Will result in

> Movie1,Movie2,Movie3

Comment: yup :) I'm storing it into session

Comment: I would just remove the foreach and change my code to:
$_SESSION['movie'] = implode(',', $movie);